# Unknown "________ would like to send a message to 45567" notification

Tags: notifications, sms

I keep getting these random SMS permission notifications. The app or service requesting to send the message is [always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPHF3.jpg) [changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2zi3.jpg).

- Pixel 2 XL on Android 9 on Freedom Mobile in Canada.
- Play Protect and Malwarebytes don't detect any malicious apps.

How do I determine what's causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue **specific to Freedom Mobile users** happening since May 9, 2019. Possibly caused by a software update from Freedom around that time, it appears to **affect Google Phone (beta) users with Visual Voicemail enabled.**

---

#### Background

There is [a thread](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/5828752?hl=en) on Google's official support for Pixel Phone, which mentions the same issue about some multiple random processes requesting permission to send an SMS to 45567 on multiple setups:

- Device model: Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL, Pixel 3, Pixel 3 XL,
- Android version: Pie, Q (beta)
- Process name: com.android.sdm.plugin, Connectivity manager, Oemdmtrigger, com.qualcomm.data, uceShimService, Phone and Messaging St..., Modem Service, SDMService, [etc.]
- Software update: After the May security patch, or after an update to "Carrier Services" and "Actions Services" but before the May security patch.

#### Temporary fix/workaround

As per [Matthew Naugler Klassen's post](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/5828752?msgid=5879714), the (temporary) fix is to disable Visual Voicemail in Google's Phone app:

1. Open **Phone** app
2. Open **Settings**
3. Under **Voicemail**, disable **Visual Voicemail**

#### Additional Remarks

Freedom Mobile seems to aware and has acknowledged the issue, promising to escalate it and deliver the fix as soon as possible.